# How insert gridview in mysql?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In advance I apologize for my English, I am Latin and my English is not very good.

My question is:

I would like to know how I can insert all the data of my gridview into mysql through a save button. That is, I dont want to insert the rows one by one, if not all rows when I press the save button.

I'm using vb.net on the asp.net platform without mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you are right its a bad idea to update rows one by one. 
 a good practice is to fill `dataset` or `datatable` object and then update your database table.
 use [MySqlDataAdapter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm) Class and its [.Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19c81fk) method.
 here is a short example:

```
 Private Sub Foo()

        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(MyConString)
        Dim sQuery As String = "Select * from Table"
        Dim myDA As New MySqlDataAdapter(sQuery, connection)
        Dim cmb As New MySqlCommand(myDA,connection)
        Dim MyDT As New DataTable() ' <- datatable must be filled with data from the datagrid

        myDA.Fill(MyDT)
        ' * Add new rows or delete/update existing one
        ' * and update the DataTable using 
        myDA.Update(MyDT)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.

I just implemented the solution that you gave me. And I get the following exception: Fill: The SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized. "

Comment: updated my answer and switched  `Dim cmb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(myDA)` to `Dim cmb As New MySqlCommand(myDA,connection)`